# Text place differently when a path point is changed from 0 to 1.4e-14

Tags: macos, core-graphics, core-text

In the code below when creating a hexagon and painting text, the text is positioned differently when a y changed from 0 to 1.42109e-14. Seems like a bug to me but thought I'd ask before reporting in case I'm missing something.

In the first image (y = 1e-14 for a point) you can see the text is calculated with a gap, whereas in the second when y = 0 it formats as expected.

This is from a drawing program and as the hexagon is resized the text moves around, so a bit annoying, workaround is to copy the y values to each.

[image]

[image]

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import Cocoa
import PlaygroundSupport

class CustomView: NSView {
    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        // Add your drawing code here.
        let backgroundColor = NSColor.red

        let path = CGMutablePath()
        let context : CGContext = (NSGraphicsContext.current?.cgContext)!
        context.scaleBy(x: 1, y: -1)
        context.translateBy(x: 0, y: 0)

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x:146.277, y:-84.84))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 109.708, y: 0))
//        This formats as expected
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 36.5693, y:0))
//        This formats with a gap above the text
//        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 36.5693, y:1.42109e-14))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: -84.84))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 36.5693, y: -169.68))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 109.708, y: -169.68))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 146.277, y: -84.84))
        path.closeSubpath()


        context.addPath(path)
        context.setLineWidth(1)
        context.setStrokeColor(CGColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1 ))
        context.drawPath(using: CGPathDrawingMode.stroke)



        let text = NSAttributedString(string: "hello there some test text")
        let framesetter : CTFramesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(text)
        let frame =
            CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter,
                                     CFRangeMake(0, CFAttributedStringGetLength(text)),
                                     path, nil)

        CTFrameDraw(frame, context)

    }

    override open var isFlipped: Bool { get { return true }}

}


let customView = CustomView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = customView
```

OSX High Sierra 10.13.6, Xcode 9.2

Comment: I know everyone hates when this is linked but [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) may be relevant. Why are you attempting to draw text at the absurd coordinate of 1.4e-14? This is the sort of weirdness that Apple should've hit in QA (since this is a bug) but there is no real reason to end up here

Comment: As I said its from a drawing program, so as I move the sides of the hexagon with the mouse it moves the points so it has different values depending on the mouse position. Indeed to solve it I've found I can't have any decimal points in the y coordinates of the points of the border of the hexagon, so I just round these prior to building the path to format the text. I raised it here because it seemed surprising to me there'd be such a fairly obvious text rendering bug after so many years, so I was half expecting someone to say, no, no you have to do this - but seems not.

Comment: I know [all too much](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52030633/1166266) about core text bugs that should’ve been found a long time ago. Core Text is probably the most neglected part of the platform